# Find a recurrence relation for the number of bit strings of length n that contain the string 01

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Here I have an example question. I'm not asking the actual question but the logic behind it.

> *Find a recurrence relation for the number of bit strings of length n that contain the string 01*

In such questions we start from -for example- the case that string has the length of *n-2*. And adding up 0's or 1's. Does it matter to add these substrings to front or end of the the string of length *n-2* to cover all the possible cases ?

Comment: HINT: What is a string that does not contain the string $01$? It's a string of the form $11\dots1100\dots00$ (some $1$s and then some $0$s).

Comment: actually I'm not asking what is the answer, I'm asking the general logic

Comment: There isn't much of a general logic, apart from a gut feeling and intuition you get from solving a lot of different problems and seeing their solutions. At least, there isn't one that can easily be put into words.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that as soon as we have a zero anywhere in the string, the only thing we can put after it is another zero, we can always add a zero to the end of any valid string, and any sting of ones is a valid string.